# Can't change back button title id a title of a navigation item is to long

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, xcode5, back-button

I have a simple navigation controller containing two controllers: master and detail. I set a back button in the master controller

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"back to first" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

I set a title in the detail controller:

```
self.title = @"title";
```

Everything works fine. I have a back button and a title. But if i set a long title like that

```
    self.title = @"very-very-very-very long title";
```

The standrad "Back" button appears instead of my back button. Is it a bug or some subtle "feature" of Apple?

Comment: try to see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235524/backbarbuttonitem-gets-renamed-in-ios-7-when-there-is-a-long-title at the end of question there is an EDIT

Comment: Yep, there is said that long titles tend back button to be changed. I guess I will never know reasons of such behaviour.